# layout_gravity and z-order in framelayout not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to stackoverflow so be gentle please :)

I am porting new recent apps views into an existing SystemUI so I'm working with xml and smali rather than Java.  However my problems relate to layout xmls so should be OK to ask here.  Specifically I am porting the new Android L style recents from ParanoidAndroid into our SystemUI, so it is the new cardstack view. Here is my status_bar_recent_panel_cardstack.xml which sets up the recents view and contains the scroll view which contains the actual cardstack:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView android:id="@id/recents_root" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:foreground="@drawable/bg_protect_transparent" systemui:recentItemLayout="@layout/status_bar_recent_item"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:systemui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.systemui">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/recents_bg_protect" android:background="@drawable/status_bar_recents_background_cardstack" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:clipChildren="false">
        <com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsVerticalScrollView android:layout_gravity="start|bottom|center" android:id="@id/recents_container" android:scrollbars="none" android:fadingEdge="vertical" android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/status_bar_recents_scroll_fading_edge_length" android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stackFromBottom="true" android:divider="@null" android:layout_marginEnd="0.0dip">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/recents_linear_layout" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsVerticalScrollView>
        <include android:id="@id/recents_no_apps" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/status_bar_no_recent_apps" />
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="top|right|center" android:id="@id/recents_clear" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="50.0dip" android:layout_height="50.0dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_recents_clear" android:scaleType="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView>
```

And here is the layout which defines each card in the stack in case it has a bearing on my question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@id/recent_item" android:padding="@dimen/status_bar_recents_card_margin" android:clipChildren="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@id/app_thumbnail" android:background="@drawable/status_bar_recent_card_shadow" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/app_thumbnail_image" android:paddingTop="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_color_bar_height" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/app_top_colored_bar" android:background="@color/status_bar_recents_app_bar_color" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_color_bar_height">
            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/app_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_color_bar_icon_size" android:layout_margin="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_color_bar_icon_margin" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:maxWidth="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_icon_max_width" android:maxHeight="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_icon_max_height" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_color_bar_label_size" android:textColor="@color/status_bar_recents_app_label_color_dark" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/app_label" android:fadingEdge="horizontal" android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/status_bar_recents_text_fading_edge_length" android:layout_width="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_label_width" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:importantForAccessibility="no" android:textAlignment="viewStart" android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/status_bar_recents_app_label_left_margin" android:layout_toEndOf="@id/app_icon" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@id/app_thumbnail_border" android:background="@drawable/status_bar_recent_card_border" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<View android:id="@id/recents_callout_line" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" />
<TextView android:id="@id/app_description" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have two problems.  Firstly the Clear All button, set up as the recents_clear imageView in the first layout, does not appear above the cardstack but rather is obscured behind it and therefore not clickable.  Why is the Z order in which the items are defined not being recognised, an is there a way to force it to the front?

Image (clear all button bottom right obscured by cardstack) - https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ItnAYg0eQ3Y/VEQqt7BvBGI/AAAAAAAAC7Y/lZ3S1NgOUjk/w492-h875-no/2014-10-19.jpg

And secondly, I have added the ability to scale down the cardstack programmatically by applying a scale factor to the card width.  However when I reduce the card size I want to centre the stack, but no matter what layout_gravity I apply to any or all of the elements in both layouts the cardstack remains aligned to the left side of the ultimate parent (less the padding).  How can I centre the scaled down cards?

Image (scaled down cardstack still left aligned in parent) - https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-SbinxvpcOyQ/VES_O2LMjGI/AAAAAAAAC84/iKzsnM92_VI/w492-h875-no/8802401609983476689

Comment: first if you are using eclipse click ctrl+shift+f. this will layout the xml in a readable format

Comment: Not using Eclipse as AFAIK you can't decompile an existing apk and import back into Eclipse, so just working with decompiled files in proprietory editor (Virtuous Ten Studio, Notepad++, etc)

Comment: Another thought - is the Z order defined by the order declared in the layout xml superceded by the order in which the elements are declared programmatically (in onFinishInflate for instance)?

Comment: Yes. The order of the elements are the Z order from bottom to top

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't ask very well.  I understand that the items declared last in the layout xml will be topmost in the view stack.  The problem I have is that the clear all button (recents_clear in the first xml above) always appears obscured by the card stack which is held in recents_container which is defined BEFORE recents_clear in the layout and therefore should appear before the clear all button in the Z-order.  I was therefore asking if something in the code could supercede the xml z order.